# Writing php Time() to mysql using

Tags: php, function, time

I want to log the time that a user posted a message and display it in a Twitter like fashion.

I found a function that does this but it does not work with mysqls Timestamp type.

In the instructions it says that it uses the time()format to calculate it. How should I be writing the times to my Database in order for it to work???

This is the code:

```
function newTime($tm,$rcs = 0) {
    // http://snipplr.com/view/17338/
    $cur_tm = time(); $dif = $cur_tm-$tm;
    $pds = array('second','minute','hour','day','week','month','year','decade');
    $lngh = array(1,60,3600,86400,604800,2630880,31570560,315705600);
    for($v = sizeof($lngh)-1; ($v >= 0)&&(($no = $dif/$lngh[$v])<=1); $v--); if($v < 0) $v = 0; $_tm = $cur_tm-($dif%$lngh[$v]);
    $no = floor($no); if($no <> 1) $pds[$v] .='s'; $x=sprintf("%d %s ",$no,$pds[$v]);
    if(($rcs == 1)&&($v >= 1)&&(($cur_tm-$_tm) > 0)) $x .= time_ago($_tm);
    return $x."ago";
}
```

Comment: You may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344852/can-my-php-time-difference-function-be-improved

Comment: - `for($v = sizeof($lngh)-1[...]` ?? why not simply use count()?
- your function is called `newTime()`, but you recursivelly call this down the code path as `time_ago()`...
not even bothering with the one-line syntax and wird conditions that i have no ideea what are doing..
This seems to be written in a C-style syntax, are you sure this snippet actually works?:) did you tested it on an isolated case?

Answer (score 1):

I refuse to try and make sense out of *that* bloody mess :) Still laughing out loud.

However, if you want to import timestamps into a mySQL DATETIME field - which I think is what you want - you can use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime):

```
INSERT INTO tablename (fieldname) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME('1234567890'));
```

Comment: Why did you delete 'I laught when I saw that code', it was 100% true.

Comment: @Lekensteyn I deleted it because I decided to answer. Yeah.... I'm still chuckling, too :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to save the actual timestamp to the database you can just use the mysql function NOW() for that:

```
INSERT INTO tablename SET timefieldname = NOW():
```

You can than read that timestamp from the database and use the function to convert the diffrence to something like "30 minutes ago".

Comment: that would be the way this problem should be handled

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED IT:

DID

$posttime = time();

INSERT INTO tablename (fieldname) VALUES ($posttime));

Comment: @user you can edit your original question rather than posting an answer.

Comment: @user You are aware that this will store the UNIX timestamp in the database, not the datetime value?

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want MySQL (instead of your code) to call the C-library function (time_t) time( ), have a look at the MySQL function UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) as a way to give FROM_UNIXTIME( ) its argument.

The return value of UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) fits perfectly in an INTEGER(10) field.