# PHP function that displays time stamps as 1d for 1 day ago, 43s for 43 seconds etc

Tags: php, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: producing relative date/time from timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690504/php-producing-relative-date-time-from-timestamps)

Pretty much as the title says, would be perfect for my website and have looked on google with no luck. Anyone have any idea how i could make/find one?

Comment: Just deduct -43 from current time(), or -86400 for a day.

Comment: Did you try writing any code? this should be pretty straightforward. There's also a lot of questions about this already, many which don't match exactly but may be of use anyway. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344852/can-my-php-time-difference-function-be-improved) for example.

Comment: @EmilVikström Neither produce the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

google (time ago php) gave me this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/time-ago-function/

Looks plain simple but solid to me (not tested)

Comment: Perfect thank you for actually providing something useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with some basic math. Find the difference between time() and your timestamp. One year is 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; one month is 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; one day is 60 * 60 * 24; one hour is 60 * 60; one minute is 60.

Just find out how many years you have, and subtract them out of the total and store them in a variable.

Then find out how many months you have, and subtract them out of the total and store them in a variable.

Then find out how many days you have, and subtract them out of the total and store them in a variable.

Then find out how many hours you have, and subtract them out of the total and store them in a variable.

Then find out how many minutes you have, and subtract them out of the total and store them in a variable.

The remainder is how many seconds you have; store them in a variable.

Then print out the desired string, using all of those variables, or if it's in a function or class method, just return that string (or, better yet, an array that contains the years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds).